# Read a TCP socket's sequence number using APIs available in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets, tcp

Do any of the APIs available in PHP allow me to read from a TCP socket the TCP state machine's current sequence number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(AFAIK) No.

This would require access to the TCP header, which none of the sockets-based extensions ([sockets](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) or [streams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php)) will provide access to.

`SOCK_STREAM` only provides the data payload, it does not (again, AFAIK) allow you get any information about the low level internal workings of the stream - because, in theory, you shouldn't need to worry about it.

It *may* (?) be possible to implement a TCP stream using `SOCK_RAW`, in which case you could *probably* get access to this information, but I'm not even 100% confident about that, and you can be certain that even if it is, it would not be worth the bother.

Having said all of that - depending on how good your lower level coding skills are, you may be able to build a PHP extension to interface with [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html). You also *might* be able to do something by `exec()`ing [tcpdump](http://www.tcpdump.org/tcpdump_man.html), as long as it is available on the host system - although equally, I sort of doubt it, I suspect this would be very difficult if even possible to implement in a language that does not support multi-threading. Either of these options would require examining the payloads of packets and comparing them with what you had sent from PHP to sync up the data with the SEQ numbers.

Comment: Thanks, DaveRandom. An extension isn't an option because what I'm writing needs to work in a wide range of deployment contexts. For the same reason, `exec()` and the rest are out because safe mode is rather common.